# publish_checkins permission July 2013 Breaking changes

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I got a developer alert for my facebook app which i use to login from phone gap. It says that

MyApp, is currently using the following deprecated features: The publish_checkins extended permission.

But I'm not using this kind of permission! I'm only using user_birthday, email, user_likes, user_location and publish_actions.

How can I remove the alert and migrate to the July 2013 Version without getting problems?

Thanks for your help!

Sebastian

Comment: I got the same alert, the permissions I am using are : email,user_birthday,user_about_me,friends_birthday,friends_location,read_friendlists. So I believe it's location related permissions like user_location would be causing problems.

Comment: Me too! Same alert, and I'm not even requesting any permissions, my app is a page tab with a news feed.

Comment: Same here, the only permission I request is `publish_stream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to the Advanced Tab, in the app configuration, and activated "July 2013 Breaking Changes". The warning is gone, the app is still working fine.

Comment: We did the same and everything is still working fine... so, no worries, just accept the breaking changes.